# If $f$ is an entire function of order $\lambda$ then $f'$ also has order $\lambda$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> If $f$ is an entire function of order $\lambda$ then $f'$ also has order $\lambda$

Can someone show me how to prove this or point me in the right direction? My definition is an entire function $f$ has finite order $\lambda$ if for $\epsilon>0$ we have $|f(z)| < $ exp$(|z|^{\lambda + \epsilon})$ for all $|z|$ sufficiently large. I also have that $\lambda = $ inf$\{ a : |f(z)| < $ exp$(|z|^{a}) $ for $|z|$ sufficiently large}, though I'm not sure if that will be useful here. I had to show the order of the sum of two functions is less than or equal to the max of the order of each function in an earlier problem, but I'm not sure how to go about this for $f'$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a Cauchy Integral Theorem type of problem. Just a suggestion, though.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm unsure how that would come into play here, care to elaborate on how you think Cauchy's may apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote with
$$
 M(r, f) = \max\{ |f(z)| : |z| \le r \}
$$
the maximum of $|f|$ on disks of radius $r$. It follows from Cauchy's integral formula for the derivative that
$$
 M(r, f') \le M(r+1, f) \, ,
$$
which implies $\lambda(f') \le \lambda(f)$. (For the details, see for example [$f$ is entire, show that the order of $f'$ is less than or equal to that of $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4308308/42969) .)

For the other direction note that
$$
 f(r e^{i \phi}) = f(0) + \int_0^r f'(t e^{i \phi})e^{i \phi} \, dt
$$
implies
$$
 M(r, f) \le |f(0)| + r M(r, f') \, .
$$
from which $\lambda(f) \le \lambda(f')$ follows in a similar way.

Comment: Great answer! Seeing someone who is much more of an expert give a hint/solution similar to my hint makes me feel like my intuition was in the right place.

Comment: @Clayton: You surely had the right idea. If I were to be quite pedantic then I could mention that “Cauchy integral theorem” and “Cauchy integral  formula” are different theorems :) I assume that you meant the latter in your comment.